# Using first object's value to find corresponding value in second object

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, jsonpath

I'm using [JSON Path parser](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to parse some data. Here is an example of the source data:

```
{
"people": [
    {
        "initials": "RF",
        "sport": "T"
    },
    {
        "initials": "LM",
        "sport": "F"
    }
],
"definitions": {
    "RF": {
        "def_1": "Roger Federer",
        "def_2": "Roger"
    },
    "LM": {
        "def_1": "Lionel Messi",
        "def_2": "Lionel"
    },
    "T": {
        "def_1": "Tennis"
    },
    "F": {
        "def_1": "Football"
    }
}
}
```

Now, if I use only the array (`people`), it's almost useless, `RF` and `T` doesn't mean much. However, in the object (`definitions`) they are defined. `RF` means `Roger Federer` and `T` is `Tennis`, so I need to import those two as well. I can easily import `RF` and `T`, but I'm struggling to find a query to connect `RF` and `T` to `Roger Federer` and `Tennis`.

First I need to specify context (root) and then names of the objects. Here is an example:

```
Context: $.[]
Query: initials
Result is: RF
```

When I import all of this in a node, this example works well to import array (`people`) data.

This is what I can successfully import now:

```
Field1 value: RF
Field2 value: T
```

What I need:

```
Field1 value: RF
Field2 value: T
**Field4 value: Roger Federer**
**Field5 value: Tennis**
```

Basically, I want to describe better what I get from the `people` array. This is one of the combinations that I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
Context: $.[]
Query: initials.def_1
Query: people.initials.def_1
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

XPath sounds like overkill for such a simple data structure. Perhaps there are other reasons you need to use XPath, but this is really easy in pure JavaScript. For example:

```
var data = {
    "people": [
        {
            "initials": "RF",
            "sport": "T"
        }, {
            "initials": "LM",
            "sport": "F"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "RF": {
            "def_1": "Roger Federer",
            "def_2": "Roger"
        },
        "LM": {
            "def_1": "Lionel Messi",
            "def_2": "Lionel"
        },
        "T": {
            "def_1": "Tennis"
        },
        "F": {
            "def_1": "Football"
        }
    }
};

data.people.forEach( function( person ) {
    var name = data.definitions[person.initials].def_1;
    var sport = data.definitions[person.sport].def_1;
    console.log( name, 'plays', sport );
});
```

Logs:

```
Roger Federer plays Tennis
Lionel Messi plays Football
```

Comment: Ah, roger that. I added an xpath tag to your question to help the XPath experts spot it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using XPath because CMS I'm using (Drupal) has a nice module that utilizes XPath and parses data from specific URLs in regular intervals. Since it makes the whole integration much easier than a custom solution, I would prefer to use XPath if it's possible in any way.